# Help transferring Ether Tokens using Parity

Tags: ether, parity

I configured Parity to trade Ether to BNT. I followed the steps here https://blog.bancor.network/how-to-trade-your-bnt-using-parity-6061dca37354 and funded my EtherToken Contract.

This is the transaction information:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x41bf1a17ee1e8cd07655ecfa0501f6d4a688f33e26296bd44c963c473799d238

I am now trying to withdrawal the Ether and transfer it back to my wallet. However, Parity gives me an error that there are insufficient funds. I also try checking the balance of the EtherToken contract and it says 0. Can you tell from the transaction info above if my Ether is gone? I am hoping that someone can help me as I am new to using Parity and this is the first time I have setup contracts.

Thank you,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

To transfer an ERC-20 token like BNT you need ETH in your account to cover the gas costs.

Looking at the blockchain, it seems you figured it out at some point and funded your account with Ether to move your Bancor Network tokens.